# Was Carlton Banks actually short?

Tags: the-fresh-prince-of-bel-air

In the US television series The Fresh Prince of Bel Air, the main character Will Smith regularly mocks his cousin Carlton Banks for his height.

Is Carlton Banks actually short in the series? Compared to his father and Will Smith, that seems to be the case, however, how does he compare to the other cast members throughout the series?

Answer (score 8):

The actor certainly is, in terms of average male height... though there is a lot of joking about how short actors tend to be.

Alfonso Ribeiro, the actor who plays him is only 5'6" (1.68m). To compare, Will Smith is 6'2" (1.88m) and James Avery is 6'5" (1.96m).

To compare, the [average height of males in the US is 5'9.5" (1.77m)](http://www.livestrong.com/article/289265-what-is-the-average-adult-male-height/) (2007-2010).

Other adult male characters' heights:

- [Jazz](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0870039/bio?ref_=nm_ov_bio_sm): 5'9.5" (1.77m)
- [Geoffrey Butler](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0545186/bio?ref_=nm_ov_bio_sm): 5'8" (1.73m)

Now, he is taller than his 5'4" (1.63m) tall little sister, Ashley ([Tatyana Ali](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0004700/bio?ref_=nm_ov_bio_sm)), but not his "mom", Vivian ([Janet Huber](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0399494/bio?ref_=nm_ov_bio_sm)), and older sister, Hillary ([Karyn Parsons](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0663854/bio?ref_=nm_ov_bio_sm)), who are both 5'7" (1.70m). That being said, we generally split the genders when talking about height anyways, which is why I have separated them out.

---

Now, all of this is really out-of-universe evidence... because an [actor's actual height and the height of the character they play aren't always the same](https://www.washingtonpost.com/entertainment/movies/the-decision-to-cast-tom-cruise-as-jack-reacher/2012/12/14/194b3b6a-3e42-11e2-ae43-cf491b837f7b_story.html?utm_term=.6eaaec2042df)... I don't have any evidence that the height jokes were part of the casting process for the show - it's possible that Carlton's height jokes came about **because of** Alfonso's short stature.

Comment: The problem was more having normal to tall other cast members.  In a Tom Cruise movie, Carlton would be manly-tall.